# Gwt NavigableSet no source found

Tags: java, gwt, treemap

The following error appear when I'm using NavigableSet to get the decending key set of a TreeMap:
`[ERROR] [workflow] - Line 159: No source code is available for type java.util.NavigableSet<E>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] [workflow] - Line 159: The method descendingKeySet() is undefined for the type TreeMap<Integer,String>`

Here is the code I use:
`NavigableSet<Integer> nmap = selectedRow.descendingMap();`

Does someone know where the error comes from ?
(For information i've imported the right class: java.util.NavigableSet )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough rep for a comment... sorry.  What version of GWT are you using?  It looks like there is a bug here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4236

Fixed in 2.7.0 RC1

Comment: @Theasc721 sounds like Ian has your answer then - the bug was fixed since your two-year-old release came out.